# How to use DoctrineExtensions Blameable from the command line?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

I am using [DoctrineExtensions Blameable](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/blameable.md) to store the user who created an entity, and when making a HTTP request with JWTs, all is working as desired.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

#[ORM\Entity]
class Foo
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    private int $id;
    
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: UserInterface::class)]
    #[Gedmo\Blameable(on: 'create')]
    private ?UserInterface $createBy = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text')]
    private $name;

    public function getId():int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCreateBy(): ?UserInterface
    {
        return $this->createBy;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now, instead of making a HTTP request to a webserver, I wish to use a command line to create an entity.

My first attempt was to manually create a token with the appropriate user, however, was not successful.

I next tried to set the user on the BlameableListener, and `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher` shows me `Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\EventListener\BlameListener::onKernelRequest()`, but I don't know how to access the listener in order to call the `setUserValue()` method.

How can DoctrineExtensions Blameable be used from the command line?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

final class AddFoo extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:add-user';

    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        // Get user input
        
        $superUser = $this->getSuperUser($superUserEmail, $superUserPassword);

        // Somehow I need to let Blamable know the "logged on" user.
        
        // Option 1.  Fake the token.
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($superUser, 'main', $superUser->getRoles());
        // Maybe need to authenticate token?
        $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);

        // Option 2.  Somehow call Gedmo\Blameable\BlameableListener::setUserValue($superUser);

        $newEntity = $this->createNewFoo($fooName);

        $this->entityManager->persist($newEntity)
        $this->entityManager->flush()
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**POTENTIAL ANSWER** - Don't know if the following is the best approach but seems to work.

```
services:
    App\Command\AddFoo:
        arguments:
            $blameableListener: '@stof_doctrine_extensions.listener.blameable'
```

Comment: Why not if it works in the Symfony way? Anyway any answer should be added in the answer section and not inside the question. Then you will be able to chose (or change) the "best" answer in the case you will receive others.

Comment: @gp_sflover  Thanks for your response.  If someone provides this as an answer, I would rather select their answer than my own.  If I don't get any answers, I will post it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to config.service.yaml.

```
services:
    App\Command\AddFoo:
        arguments:
            $blameableListener: '@stof_doctrine_extensions.listener.blameable'
```

And then within `AddFoo.php`...

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Gedmo\Blameable\BlameableListener;

final class AddFoo extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:add-foo';

    public function __construct(private BlameableListener $blameableListener)
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        // ...
        $this->blameableListener->setUserValue($this->getUserFromEmailAndPassword());
        // ..
    }
}
```